# Whats the best approach to making a web application for drawing on and modifying an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

Whats the best approach to making a web application for drawing on and modifying an image?  Should be able to draw on, add text etc.  I have been hearing a lot about SVG, but is that a required download for the user to view the application then?  Whats the best way to handle this?  What language? etc.  Thanks!  Preferred: PHP jQuery javascript html css  Thanks you!

Comment: Not knowing exactly what you are trying to do, I recommend looking at this http://raphaeljs.com/ as it incorporates cross browser vector graphics. However, I think the interface to actually allow the user to draw would have to be created (this would just act as the 'engine' to facilitate the drawing).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the HTML5 Canvas element:

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/canvas.html

You can draw on (over) the image as well as add text. No install required.